# coredata how to change default NSSet to NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, core-data

CoreData one-to-many default to generate `NSSet` ,how to change `NSSet` to `NSMutableArray`?I try to change it manually,but get error:

```
 _NSFaultingMutableSet filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ed35e40'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`NSSet` has the method `allObjects`, which returns an `NSArray`.

To get an `NSMutableArray` you could do this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:myCoreDataObject.mySet.allObjects];
```

Note: order is not guaranteed to be the same every time (sets aren't ordered). If order is important to you, consider an `NSOrderedSet` instead.

See also the docs on `NSSet`:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html

PS:

The reason you're getting said error:

`NSSet` (or `_NSFaultingMutableSet` for that matter) doesn't have a method called `filteredArrayUsingPredicate`.

Comment: How to update NSArray if myCoreDataObject.mySet has been changed?

Comment: @jay Uh, carefully...? ;) It's bad form to ask a new question as a comment... Open a new question instead.